# Delete range of rows using a prefix key

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-bigtable

I'm using the package 'org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client' for dataflow to manage Google's BigTable data.

Example to delete a row:

```
key = "PROV|CLI|800|20160714|8|30302.30301|ES";
byte[] byteKey = Bytes.toBytes(key);
Delete delete = new Delete(byteKey);
```

This works fine but I need a way to delete all rows that start with they key 'PROV|CLI|800|'

Is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 7):

Cloud Bigtable has a feature to do this efficiently via [`AbstractBigtableAdmin. deleteRowRangeByPrefix(byte[])`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-client/blob/master/bigtable-hbase-parent/bigtable-hbase/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/AbstractBigtableAdmin.java#L633):

```java
Connection c = ...;
AbstractBigtableAdmin admin = (AbstractBigtableAdmin) c.getAdmin();
admin.deleteRowRangeByPrefix(Bytes.toBytes("PROV|CLI|800|"));
admin.close();
```

Comment: Is there anyway using the package "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client"?

Comment: You can create a scan with a PrefixFilter, iterate over the results and delete them using table.batch(List<Delete>)